# align long text in flex box same way as short text

Tags: flexbox

how can I let flex box stay same when it has long text or short text

html

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b" style="background-color:red"></div>
    <div class="b" style="background-color:yellow"></div>
    <div class="b" style="background-color:green">
       aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.a {
   display:flex;
   justify-content: space-between
}
.b {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use 'overflow-wrap: break-word;' on the a class selector in your stylesheet to accomplish your goal.

EDIT: I did a little more research and I think 'flex-wrap: wrap;' might also fix the issue.